# Increase the value of a variable in a vector using ifelse if R

Tags: r, if-statement

I have an `ifelse` statement and want to increase the the variable by `1` each time the condition is met and drop the count to by subtracting the entire count `-count` if the condition is not met.

```
df = data.frame(indicator= c(60,61,58,40,70,80))

position = 0
df$sig = ifelse((df$indicator > 60), 
       (position = position + 1), 
       -position)
```

The answer would look like this

```
df = data.frame(indicator= c(60,61,58,40,70,80),
                sig = c(0,1,0,0,1,2))
```

This is to keep track of a trading position (buy if over 60 and sell if under but keep track of how big the position is.

How can I do this in R?

Comment: how do you plan to store the results? are you going to use a database?

Comment: I want to store them in a vector/dataframe

Comment: I've edited your Q to make the indicator numeric. As arithmetic with characters is "probably" not intended.

Comment: @StephenHenderson Yes thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe like this, with `dplyr` and `rleid` from the `data.table` package:

```
df = data.frame(indicator= c(60,61,58,40,70,80))

library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
df %>%
  group_by(group = rleid(indicator > 60)) %>%
  mutate(sig = cumsum(indicator > 60)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-group) %>%
  as.data.frame
```

Output:

```
  indicator sig
1        60   0
2        61   1
3        58   0
4        40   0
5        70   1
6        80   2
```

---

Or alternatively, only with `data.table`:

```
df = data.frame(indicator= c(60,61,58,40,70,80))

library(data.table)
setDT(df)[,sig := cumsum(indicator > 60), rleid(indicator > 60)]
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Good one! I posted a kind of similar aproach with vanilla R below

Answer (score 3):

With vanilla R, you can use `rle` and `ave` + `cumsum`:

```
rl <- rle(df$indicator > 60)
rl$values <- seq_along(rl$values)

df$sig <- ave(df$indicator, inverse.rle(rl), FUN = function(x) cumsum(x > 60))
```

The result:

```
> df
  indicator sig
1        60   0
2        61   1
3        58   0
4        40   0
5        70   1
6        80   2
```

Comment: That's a nice solution too :)

Comment: `transform(df,sig=ave(x<-indicator>60, cumsum(!x), FUN = cumsum))`

Answer (score 0):

```
count = 0
count = count + sum(ifelse(df$colour == "green", 1, 0))
```

However you could more directly just do this:

```
count = sum(df$colour == "green")
```

This works because TRUE is equal to 1 and FALSE is equal to 0 when you sum them.

Comment: This was just a simplified example, I can't use count I. I need to calculate a running balance. Let me update the example.

Answer (score 0):

That would be:

```
position <- 0

df <- data.frame(indicator= c("60","61","58","40","70","80"))
df$indicator <- as.numeric(df$indicator)

df_sum <- sum(df$indicator)

position <- ifelse(df_sum > 60, position + 1, position -1)
```

Comment: This evaluates the entire vector as one statement but I want to evaluate the vector line by line so the count is running as in the example answer.

Comment: @Davis your OP is very unclear. Please try to structure your thoughts a little bit better next time.